# wp_redirect and is_page_template is not working?

Tags: php, wordpress, if-statement, redirect, hook-wordpress

I am trying to detect the page of the user and then redirect based on that, just of testing purposes now since i want to verify user role and if they are a certain role they will be redirected out from the page. Anyway the following code is not working despite research and trial and error:

```
function wpse12535_redirect_sample() {

    if(is_page_template('list-projects.php')) {
        wp_redirect('http://url.com.au/profile');
    }

}

add_action( 'init', 'wpse12535_redirect_sample' );
```

Answer (score 2):

> **NOTE**
>
> 1. You should add `exit()` or `die()` after `wp_redirect()`;
> 2. Use `wp` instead on `init`. This will ensure you the template is already loaded.
> 3. If the template file is under subdirectory then you have to check with that part. Ex:
>      `/wp-content/themes/my_active_theme/page-templates/list-projects.php`,
>      then you have to check `page-templates/list-projects.php`

Here is the code that will work for you:

```
function wh_redirect_sample()
{
    if (basename(get_page_template()) == 'list-projects.php')
    {
        wp_redirect('http://url.com.au/profile');
        exit(); //always remember to add this after wp_redirect()
    }
}

add_action('wp', 'wh_redirect_sample');
```

---

Alternate Method:

```
function wh_redirect_sample()
{
    //if list-projects.php is under sub directory say /wp-content/themes/my_active_theme/page-templates/list-projects.php
    if (is_page_template('page-templates/list-projects.php'))
    {
        wp_redirect('http://url.com.au/profile');
        exit();
    }
    //if list-projects.php is under active theme directory say /wp-content/themes/my_active_theme/list-projects.php
    if (is_page_template('list-projects.php'))
    {
        wp_redirect('http://url.com.au/profile');
        exit();
    }
}

add_action('wp', 'wh_redirect_sample');
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme). Or also in any plugin php files.*
**Code is tested and works.**

Hope this helps!

Comment: Yeah this is not working i am not sure if its because i am running freelancengine theme. But yeah

Comment: check what value you have in `_wp_page_template` `metakey`.

Answer (score 1):

Add an exit to the end of your wp_redirect:

```
function wpse12535_redirect_sample() {

    if(is_page_template('list-projects.php')) {
        wp_redirect('http://url.com.au/profile');
        exit;
    }
}

add_action( 'init', 'wpse12535_redirect_sample' );
```

See https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_redirect/#description

*Note: wp_redirect() does not exit automatically, and should almost always be followed by a call to exit;:*

Edit: Raunak's answer is correct, you need to change your hook from init to wp or template_redirect actions:

https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out though i still have the initial problem of getting the function to fire when accessing the page.

Comment: +1 for your answer, one important point you missed that is `init`, it is called before the template is loaded.